# The quantization of the electromagnetic field in Peskin and Schroeder (Eq.9.52)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, path-integral, propagator

I'm working on the quantization of the electromagnetic field in Peskin (page 294).

[image]

However, I'm confused about the Eq.(9.52). Peskin says Eq.(9.51) and Eq.(9.52) are equivalent, but why? Is Eq.(9.52) derived from Eq.(9.51)?

For a real scalar field, I know
$$
D_{F}(x-y)=\left\langle 0\left|T \phi\left(x_{1}\right) \phi\left(x_{2}\right)\right| 0\right\rangle=\left. Z[J]^{-1}\left(-i \frac{\delta}{\delta J\left(x_{1}\right)}\right)\left(-i \frac{\delta}{\delta J\left(x_{2}\right)}\right) Z[J]\right|_{J=0}
$$
If we want to derive the Eq.(9.52), do we need to use it?

Comment: In 9.51 you derived $(\partial^2 g^{\mu \nu} - \partial^{\mu} \partial^{\nu})A_{\nu}$, and in evaluating a path integral fully you know (e.g. around 9.38) that you'll need the inverse of this operator to do it, but the inverse is an operator $D_{\nu \rho}(x-y)$ such that $(\partial^2 g^{\mu \nu} - \partial^{\mu} \partial^{\nu})D_{\nu \rho}(x-y) = \delta^{\mu}_{\rho}\delta^4(x-y)$, however since $(\partial^2 g^{\mu \nu} - \partial^{\mu} \partial^{\nu})\partial_{\nu} \alpha(k) =0$ the operator has a non-zero kernel and so is non-invertible, that's all 9.52 is saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that the quadratic part of the action should be invertible and the inverse gives the propagator of the field. Eq. 9.52 is trying to solve for the inverse $\tilde{D}^{\nu\rho}_F$, but you cannot because $-k^2g_{\mu\nu} + k_\mu k_\nu$ is singular. That's the exact same as saying that the quadratic action vanishes for too many field configurations for the path integral to converge.

Basically, Peskin is using two different approaches to convince you that you can't naïvely invert the matrix giving the quadratic part of the action to get the propagator—you need some tricks.

Comment: To answer more explicitly: Eqn 9.52 isn't really "derived" from 9.51, because 9.51 is just an action integral. Peskin is just saying that both statements encapsulate the same idea. Eqn 9.52 is not really "derived", it's just the statement of what it means to (attempt to) find the propagator via inversion of a matrix.